# how to simplify $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2(1+\frac{1}{n^2})}}$ to $\frac{n}{n\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+1}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I was using Symbolab to calculate a limit step by step and I do not understand one of the steps that it used to simply the equation.

The calculator simplified
$$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2(1+\frac{1}{n^2})}}$$
to
$$\frac{n}{n\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+1}}$$
can someone explain how to simplify from the first part to the second part?

Comment: Use $\sqrt{a \times b} = \sqrt{a} \times \sqrt{b}$.

Comment: wow, I didn't realize it until I saw this, the way the website formatted it made it difficult to see, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{n^2A}=n\sqrt{A}=\sqrt{A}(n)$$ for any $A$ when $n\geq 0$. In the above, $A=1+\frac{1}{n^2}$.

The choice to write $n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}$ as $\sqrt{\frac1{n^2}+1}(n)$ is poor, because it is hard to tell that the $(n)$ is outside the square root symbol, and the added parentheses is "noise."